# Flutter Bloc: Search result is not being displayed and throwing error

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a news app using newsapi.org. I have used Flutter Bloc as my state management solution. I am trying to implement the search functionality using Bloc. I think I have implemented it correctly but results are not being displayed. Please have a look at the code below and let me know what am I missing.

1. SearchNewsState class.

```
    abstract class SearchNewsState extends Equatable {
      const SearchNewsState();
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [];
    }
    
    class SearchNewsInitial extends SearchNewsState {}
    
    class SearchNewsLoadingState extends SearchNewsState {}
    
    class SearchNewsLoadedState extends SearchNewsState {
      final List<NewsArticleModel> articleList;
      const SearchNewsLoadedState({required this.articleList});
    }
    
    class SearchNewsErrorState extends SearchNewsState {
      final String errorMessage;
      const SearchNewsErrorState({required this.errorMessage});
    }
```

2. SearchNewsEvent

```
abstract class SearchNewsEvent extends Equatable {
  final String query;
  const SearchNewsEvent({required this.query});
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class StartSearchNewsEvent extends SearchNewsEvent {
  const StartSearchNewsEvent({required super.query});
}
```

3.SearchNewsBloc

```
class SearchNewsBloc extends Bloc<SearchNewsEvent, SearchNewsState> {
  NewsRepository newsRepository;
  List<NewsArticleModel> list = [];
  SearchNewsBloc(
      {required SearchNewsState initialState, required this.newsRepository})
      : super(initialState) {
    on<SearchNewsEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is SearchNewsLoadingState) {
        emit(SearchNewsLoadingState());
      } else {
        list = await newsRepository.searchNews(event.query);
        emit(SearchNewsLoadedState(articleList: list));
      }
      add(StartSearchNewsEvent(query: event.query));
    });
  }

  Stream<SearchNewsState> mapEventToState(SearchNewsEvent event) async* {
    if (event is StartSearchNewsEvent) {
      try {
        List<NewsArticleModel> articlesList = [];
        yield SearchNewsLoadingState();
        articlesList = await newsRepository.searchNews(event.query);
        yield SearchNewsLoadedState(articleList: articlesList);
      } catch (e) {
        yield SearchNewsErrorState(errorMessage: e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4.Respository.

```
Future<List<NewsArticleModel>> searchNews(String query) async {
    String url =
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/eveything?q=$query&apiKey=${NewsApiConstants.apiKey}";

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    List<NewsArticleModel> articleModelList = [];
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      for (var data in jsonData[NewsApiConstants.articles]) {
        if (data[NewsApiConstants.description].toString().isNotEmpty &&
            data[NewsApiConstants.urlToImage].toString().isNotEmpty) {
          NewsArticleModel articleModel = NewsArticleModel.fromJson(data);
          articleModelList.add(articleModel);
        }
      }
      return articleModelList;
    } else {
      // returns an empty list.
      return articleModelList;
    }
  }
```

5. SeachTextField

```
TextField(
                        controller: searchController,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                        onSubmitted: (value) {
                          print(value);
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                const SnackBar(
                                    content: Text(
                                        'Please type something to search...')));
                          } else {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => SearchedNewsResult(
                                        searchBloc:
                                            BlocProvider.of<SearchNewsBloc>(
                                                context),
                                        queryResult: value)));
                          }
                        },
```

6.SearchResultPage.

```
class SearchedNewsResult extends StatelessWidget {
  final String queryResult;
  final Bloc<SearchNewsEvent, SearchNewsState> searchBloc;

  SearchedNewsResult(
      {Key? key, required this.queryResult, required this.searchBloc})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    searchBloc.add(StartSearchNewsEvent(query: queryResult));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar('Flash News', context),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Flexible(child: Text(queryResult)),
          vertical15,
          Flexible(
            child: BlocBuilder<SearchNewsBloc, SearchNewsState>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, SearchNewsState state) {
                if (state is SearchNewsLoadingState) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else if (state is SearchNewsLoadedState) {
                  List<NewsArticleModel> articlesList = [];
                  articlesList = state.articleList;
                  return ListView.builder(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: articlesList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return NewsCard(
                            imgUrl: " ",
                            desc: articlesList[index].description ?? " ",
                            title: articlesList[index].title ?? " ",
                            content: articlesList[index].content ?? " ",
                            postUrl: " ");
                      });
                } else if (state is SearchNewsErrorState) {
                  String error = state.errorMessage;
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(error),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

7. Error that I am getting
   [image]
8. JsonData (but displaying only 1 item on the screen)
   [image]
   Thank you!.

Comment: Can you print jsonData, in Repository?

Comment: @HosseinAsadi I have updated the question, printed the jsonData response. I am getting response now, but another problem has risen, that it is displaying only 1 item out of all those responses.

Comment: So, you can show this one item into ui and state change correct!?

Comment: @HosseinAsadi yes 1 item is getting displayed. Someone said I have mixed old and new format of Bloc for showing the items in the UI. I am not good with Bloc, but trying it out to gain more confidence.

Comment: Can you print this "articlesList.length"?(In part show ListView.builder)

Comment: @HosseinAsadi I added this line ``` BlocProvider.of<SearchNewsBloc>(context)
                        .add(StartSearchNewsEvent(query: queryResult)); ``` below the else if statement that says state is SearchNewsLoadedState and it is loading all the results.

Comment: @HosseinAsadi but when I enter another search keyword, the page loads previous result and does not re-build showing new results

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your `Bloc` class. For starters, you should fully update it to the new API. You also don't need to pass in the `state` in the constructor.

Also in this line, you're comparing a `state` `SearchNewsLoadingState` to an `event`. I'm surprised the compiler even allows that.

```
 if (event is SearchNewsLoadingState) {
 emit(SearchNewsLoadingState());
}
```

That can be removed entirely because you don't need to check for event types in that way. The general idea is to use the `on` method for each event you define, not including the abstract event. So in your case, it would be simplified to this.

```
class SearchNewsBloc extends Bloc<SearchNewsEvent, SearchNewsState> {
  NewsRepository newsRepository;
// just pass initial state into super, no need to manually pass in a state into the bloc class
  SearchNewsBloc({required this.newsRepository}) : super(SearchNewsInitial()) { 
    on<StartSearchNewsEvent>(_onStartSearchNewsEvent);
  }

  Future<void> _onStartSearchNewsEvent(
      StartSearchNewsEvent event, Emitter<SearchNewsState> emit) async {
    try {
      emit(SearchNewsLoadingState());
      List<NewsArticleModel> articlesList = [];
      articlesList = await newsRepository.searchNews(event.query);
      emit(SearchNewsLoadedState(articleList: articlesList));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(SearchNewsErrorState(errorMessage: e.toString()));
    }
  }
// logging all state transitions
  @override
  void onTransition(Transition<SearchNewsEvent, SearchNewsState> transition) {
    super.onTransition(transition);
    log('$transition');
  }
}
```

I removed `list` because it is only needed in the `SearchNewsLoadedState` class.

Also here

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    searchBloc.add(StartSearchNewsEvent(query: queryResult));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar('Flash News', context),
```

A widgets `build` method is not where you want to do a network call, as you can end up making that network call way more than necessary. In this case, I'd delete that line from the build method and instead fire the event in the `onSubmitted` of the text field.

```
      onSubmitted: (value) {
                      print(value);
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(
                                content: Text(
                                    'Please type something to search...')));
                      } else {
            // firing event from here instead of the build method of SearchNewsResult
                        final searchBloc = context.read<SearchNewsBloc>();
                        searchBloc.add(StartSearchNewsEvent(query: value));
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SearchedNewsResult(
                                searchBloc:
                                    BlocProvider.of<SearchNewsBloc>(context),
                                queryResult: value),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
```

That should do it, for me it loads the full list of articles after I made those changes.

Comment: Thank a lot for helping me out. Let me try it out and I get back to you.